# meanjs crud module displays no view and redirect to home (/)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack, meanjs, mean.io

I am using mean.js version 0.3. i successfully created and configured the app and everything working without any errors. after that i wanted to use yo crud module so i ran following command

```
$ yo meanjs:crud-module customer
```

then a customers module is created under the public\modules\customers.
theni run the grunt which executed without any errors. but when i navigated to
http://127.0.0.1:3000/#!/customers

it simply gets redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/#!/
it shows no view.
am  i missing anything ?

Comment: are you sure the yo generator works with 0.3 ? I am using it on 0.4 with no problems.